# How to kill/stop remote Docker container after disconnecting SSH

Tags: docker, ssh

I have a remote docker container that I access over SSH. I start the container normally with the docker start command.

```
sudo docker start 1db52045d674
sudo docker exec -it 1db52045d674; bash
```

This starts an interactive tty in the container, which I access over ssh.
I'd like the container to kill itself if I close the SSH connection. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was hoping for a more elegant solution but in the end I launched a bash script over ssh to trap for a SIGHUP
something like:

```
trap 'docker stop CONTAINER_NAME' SIGHUP;
while sleep 5;
do echo "foo";
done;
```

so when the operator closes the SSH connection, the trap gets trigger and docker nicely stops

Answer (score 1):

`.bash_logout` is executed every time you use exit command to end a terminal session.

So you can use this file to run the docker stop command when you exit the ssh connection on the remote server.

1. Create ~/.bash_logout file if not existing.
2. Add following command to stop the docker container in this file.
   Example :

```
    docker stop container_name
```

Note: If a user closes the terminal window instead of writing the exit command, this file is not executed.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I specifically am looking for a solution where the user closes the terminal window or the SSH connection just breaks for some reason

Comment: In that case I think you can run a script on remote server when ssh connection starts, that keeps polling/checking whether ssh is connected or not. And when ssh is disconnected, it then runs the docker stop command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--init` parameter for initializing. This way, your container will be able to take over the init process and you can send a kill signal to it: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#specify-an-init-process

Start the server:

```
docker run --init \
  -p 2222:2222 \
  -e USER_NAME=user \
  -e USER_PASSWORD=pass \
  -e PASSWORD_ACCESS=true \
  -e SUDO_ACCESS=true \
  linuxserver/openssh-server
```

Just note the `--init` and `-e SUDO_ACCESS=true` parameters here.

In another (client) shell,

1. ssh into container:

```
$  ssh user@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new
Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:2222' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
user@127.0.0.1's password: 
Welcome to OpenSSH Server
```

2a. send kill signal to PID1 (`docker-init`):

```
$ sudo kill -s SIGINT 1
[sudo] password for user: 
$ Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed by remote host.
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

Container is gone.

I hope this helps.

Comment: my run cmd is like this: sudo docker run --name hb_cont --init --gpus all -it --privileged --network=host  linuxserver/openssh-server
I have root defined as the USER in my Dockerfile.
In my case, I'm actually not using the port option. I directly ssh to the hostmachine, then just run docker. Is that why this is not working for me?